# Fastest way to simulate recurrent equations in OpenCL

Tags: performance, recursion, opencl

I am trying to simulate a recurrent equation of the type

s<sub>i</sub>(t+1) = f[Σ<sub>j</sub> W<sub>ij</sub>s<sub>j</sub>(t) + v<sub>i</sub>*input(t)]

in OpenCL, where f(.) is some non-linear function (in the code below it is just a step-function with threshold th) and s(t) is some external input. Naturally, I implemented one worker for every x<sub>i</sub>. In every time-step every worker calculates the result of the equation above and subsequently this result is shared with all other workers. Therefore, all workers have to be in the same workgroup.

My current OpenCL kernel looks like this

```
__kernel void part1(__global int* s, __global float* W, __global float* Th, __global float* V, __global float* input, int N, int T)
    {
        unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);

        float value = 0;
        float v = V[i];
        float th = Th[i];  

        for(int t = 0; t < T; t++){
            value = v*input[t];
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                value = value + W[i*N + j]*s[j];
            }
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
            if (value >= th){
                s[i] = 1;
            } else {
                s[i] = 0;
            }
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this code is actually three times slower than an equivalent C-implementation. Also, I expected that a change in the number of workers should not make a huge difference (because new workers are sitting on new threads that run in parallel to the others), but actually the processing time increases linearly with the number of workers. The bottleneck seems to be the writing operation after the first barrier. Eliminating this operation (but leaving the barrier in place) cuts down the processing time by a factor of 25 and eliminates the linear dependence.

I am pretty new to OpenCL and I would appreciate any help to speed this code up!

Thanks a lot in advance!
Blue2script

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what does the j number represent? In the formula you wrote + si(t) but in the code you have *s[j]. How is this fitting together? I'm interested to know how a worker x will need the s value computed by a worker y. The speedup observed when you remove the operation between the two barriers can be explain by the fact that reading and writing in the global memory is really slow.

Comment: Dear CaptainObvious, thanks for your comment! In fact, I didn't properly align the equation with the code. The x was the s. I corrected this. But is the slowdown solely due to the writing access to the global memory? Even if I run the code on the CPU I get this slowdown. Does the C-version makes better use of the cache?

Comment: What are some typical values for N and T? Are the maximum values for these variables? Also, what work group and global dimensions are you using for the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already stated in my comment, accessing global memory is slow. Usually the hardware hides the latency by having several subgroups of threads running on the same compute unit. The subgroups I'm referring to are call warps in the NVIDIA lingo and wavefronts in the AMD one. Usually a workgroup is composed of several subgroups.

So meanwhile one subgroup waits to receive the data from the global memory another one that already has all the necessary resources can run. When the running one gets stalled because it needs to read/write data from/to the global memory another one can start running and so on.

However, in your case, because of the barriers, all the workers in all the subgroups will have to that the others wrote in the memory before being able to continue the computation (the barrier is at the workgroup level). Hence the latency hits you right in the face :).

Now, a way to improve your implementation would be to use local memory  and this time a barrier at the local memory level (with the flag CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE). The same principle I've just explained still applies but accessing local memory is much faster.

As far as I understand your code (quite likely I didn't get all the subtleties), your s array has N elements, and I guess that you also have N workers. So you create a local array of N elements and you do something like that:

```
kernel void part1(global int* s, global float* W, global float* Th, global float* V, global float* input, local int* local_s, int N, int T)
    {
        unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);
        unsigned int local_i = get_local_id(0);

        float value = 0;
        float v = V[i];
        float th = Th[i];  
        //fetch from global to local and sync before computing
        local_s[local_i] = s[i];
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        for(int t = 0; t < T; t++){
            value = v*input[t];
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                value = value + W[i*N + j]*local_s[j];
            }
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
            if (value >= th){
                local_s[i] = 1;
            } else {
                local_s[i] = 0;
            }
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
    //If necessary write some stuff to global (maybe the last s computed?)
    }
```

Now I have to warn you:

- I might have completely misunderstood your needs :)
- I've just edited your code while typing this answer, so there are most probably typos and such.
- Even using local memory, having so many barriers might still make the opencl version slower than the C one.

Note that I removed the leading __ since they are not necessary and it is easier to read in my opinion.

**EDIT**: Regarding your comment about CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE vs. CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE. A barrier is always applied at the workgroup level, so all workers within a workgroup have to hit that barrier. The flag given as parameter refers to memory access. When the flag is CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE it means that every read/write operation regarding the global memory has to be completed by every worker before any worker can continue to run the next statements. This is exactly the same with the CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE flag but for the local memory.

Comment: Dear CaptainObvious, thanks a lot for your answer! I cannot immediately test the code (the machine is at work) but I was wondering about the local vs global memory in this case. I thought "global" was referring to the whole workgroup whereas "local" was referring to the individual workers. On the other hand, if the memory was only local to the worker, a local barrier wouldn't make much sense. Hence, I am very likely missing something. Could you enlighten me? The references on OpenCL are often hard to read and to understand without a thorough IT background... Thanks again!

Comment: I have been testing copying s to the local memory and setting local barriers - but to no avail. The timings are exactly the same. I will try to put a more minimum example together. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Well the fact that at each iteration every thread needs the input of the others is not ideal at all for OpenCL. I'd say that most probably this problem is not in the group of those that can beneficiate of OpenCL